# Making svg container appear one below another on array looping

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js, svg

I have the following code where I created two svg container of different height and width and it is created for every element in the array. The code works well but I want the svg container text1 which contains **title1** to appear below the svg container text2 that displays the **title2** rather than side by side that's how it appears now, i.e., next to each other. How to make container 2 to appear just below the container 1

Here is the code

```
function draw(data) {
    data.forEach(function(d) {
        var text1 = d3.select("body").append("svg")
            .attr("width", 200)
            .attr("height", 100);

        var title1 = d.values.title1;

        text1.append("text")
            .attr("x", "50%")
            .attr("y", "10%")
            .text(title1);

        var text2 = d3.select("body").append("svg")
            .attr("width", 300)
            .attr("height", 500);

        var title2 = d.values.title2;

        text2.append("text")
            .attr("x", "40%")
            .attr("y", "10%")
            .text(title2);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You probably can solve your problems just changing your CSS. By default, SVGs will display side by side, if there is enough room in the page. In this snippet, 5 SVGs are produced (click "run code snippet"):

```js
var data = d3.range(5);

var body = d3.select("body");

var svg = body.selectAll("svg")
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", 100)
  .attr("height", 100);
```

```css
svg {
  background-color: teal;
  margin-right: 5px;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```

This is exactly the same code, but setting the `display` in the CSS:

```
  display: block;
```

Check the difference (click "run code snippet"):

```js
var data = d3.range(5);

var body = d3.select("body");

var svg = body.selectAll("svg")
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", 100)
  .attr("height", 100);
```

```css
svg {
  background-color: teal;
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: does it work for looping? for example during the second iteration I want the svg container 1 and 2 to appear side of the containers resulted from  previous iteration rather than making every thing appear one below another ???

Comment: Look, this is a *different* question. If you have another problem, please make another question.

Comment: Is there a way to do it without using JavaScript? i want use just `css`.

Comment: @SalahAdDin I don't understand your problem, so please post it as a new question, with the relevant information.